# Menu not showing in SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I have

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;


public class ActivityHome extends SherlockFragmentActivity             {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

  ...........
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

but the menu is not showing in a title bar, but in the bottom of a screen(by clicking "menu" button on device). Like by normal activity... what am i doing wrong??

menu xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_add_record"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_plus"
        android:title="@string/add"
        >
    </item>
</menu>
```

please help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get individual menu items to show in the `ActionBar` by adding the `android:showAsAction="always"` attribute

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: @user1908375: You should give jbr3zy the tick if this helped your problem.